# Execute CQL from pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra

I am trying to execute CQL from pyspark. Currently, I can read and write tables.

```
$ pyspark --packages anguenot/pyspark-cassandra:0.7.0 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=12.34.56.78

>>> sqlContext.read\
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
    .options(table="my_table", keyspace="my_keyspace")\
    .load()

+-----+-----+--------+
|cCode|pCode|   mDate|
+-----+-----+--------+
|  135|  379|20180428|
|   31|  898|20180429|
|   31|  245|20180430|
+-----+-----+--------+
```

I would like from my pyspark interface to be able to execute a `create` statement for example :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS keyspace_name.table_name 
( column_definition, column_definition, ...)
WITH property AND property ...
```

Usually, when I execute SQL on Hive, I juste have to use `sqlContext.sql()` but in that case, I need somehow to add this information `format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")` somewhere, and I just don't know where to put it.

Comment: Why you want to use PYSPARK for running a DDL like "Create table"? For running DDL you can instead use Casandra driver for Python to connect to database and execute the DDL. for further details you can refer "https://pypi.org/project/cassandra-driver/1.0.0b7/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scala/Java, there is a `CassandraConnector` class that allows to execute arbitrary commands using the `withSessionDo` function (see [docs](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md#connecting-manually-to-cassandra)).

But as per [documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/15_python.md), PySpark interface to Cassandra is limited only to work with DataFrames:

> With the inclusion of the Cassandra Data Source, PySpark can now be used with the Connector to access Cassandra data. This does not require DataStax Enterprise but you are limited to DataFrame only operations.

So the only possibility for is directly construct & use the `Cluster`/`Session` classes from [Python driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.14/getting_started/).